# Applying Natural ShapeStyle for system and asset image in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, image, swiftui, ios17

I was wondering whether applying the natural `ShapeStyle` would be feasible. However, utilizing the `.clear` color Style is not an option due to the default rendering mode in the system image being set to `.template`. This default setting leads to the disappearance of the second image.

```
import SwiftUI

struct SwiftUIView8: View {
    @State private var hasStyle: Bool = true
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            /// Asset Image
            Image("envelope.square")
                .applyStyle(hasStyle)
            /// System Image
            Image(systemName: "book")
                .applyStyle(hasStyle)
                .font(.title.weight(.bold))
            Toggle("apply Style", isOn: $hasStyle)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

private extension Image {
    func applyStyle(_ hasStyle: Bool) -> some View {
        self.renderingMode(hasStyle ? .template : .original)
            .foregroundStyle(hasStyle ? .green : .clear /* natural style */)
    }
}

#Preview {
    SwiftUIView8()
}
```

Comment: If you use `.foregroundColor` then you could use `nil` as the alternative. But unfortunately, this modifier is deprecated. What about using `.primary` style instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that using `.opacity(1)` gives the view its "natural" foreground color. I'm talking about the static factory method [`opacity`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/shapestyle/opacity(_:)-swift.type.method), not to be confused with the instance method [`opacity`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/shapestyle/opacity(_:)-swift.method) that can be applied to an existing shape style. The documentation says:

> Returns a new style based on the current style that multiplies by opacity when drawing.

So even if the current style is semi-transparent, `.opacity(1)` still would not change it. For any `x`, `x` multiplied by 1 is still `x`.

```
private extension Image {
    func applyStyle(_ hasStyle: Bool) -> some View {
        self.renderingMode(hasStyle ? .template : .original)
            .foregroundStyle(hasStyle ? AnyShapeStyle(.green) : AnyShapeStyle(.opacity(1)))
    }
}
```

Note that since `.green` and `.opacity` has different types, you need to wrap them in `AnyShapeStyle`s.

Another style you could use is [`primary`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/shapestyle/primary). This works in most cases and in my opinion is more readable than `.opacity(1)`. However, it wouldn't work when the parent view sets the foreground color to a different hierarchical style, e.g.

```
VStack {
    Text("Foo")
        .foregroundStyle(.primary)
    Text("Bar")
    // Foo will have the primary color,
    // but Bar will have the secondary color
}
.foregroundStyle(.secondary)
```